# Add query variable at the start of the url (after base url)

Tags: wordpress

i'm trying to add a query variable at the start of my urls. like adding language code in url that language management modules usually do.

for example i want this url:

> http://example.com/cities/newyork/?p=1

to show whats in this one:

> http://example.com/?p=1

and get the city as variable and newyork as it's value in the flowing function :

```
get_query_var('city_name');
```

i actually want wordpress to ignore cities/newyork and work as the way it did before.

i tried this code in my function.php, but it's not working correct :

```
add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^cities/([a-z]+)/?',
        'index.php?city_name=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}, 10, 0);
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse26388_query_vars' );
function wpse26388_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'city_name';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick with rewrite rules is that when they are modified (if you add, modify, or delete one), you need to tell WordPress to refresh and rebuild the list. To do so, you can either visit the Permalink Options page in the admin area or use the function `flush_rewrite_rules()`

```
// Add the rewrite rule and flush on plugin activation
add_action('init', function() {
add_rewrite_rule( '^cities/([a-z]+)/?', 'index.php?city_name=$matches[1]', 'top' );
flush_rewrite_rules();
    }, 10, 0);
```

Comment: my changes are effecting the site and the problem is not with flush rewrite rules. i want cities/cityname to be ingnored if it's used.

Comment: what do you mean by ignoring them?

Comment: when the cities/cityname is not ignored it will not go to /?p=1. it will try to get cities page and when it can't catch it, it will show 404 page.
i want cityname to be stored in query variables for future catch and the routing process get to ?p=1

Comment: try to use this: `add_rewrite_rule( 'cities/?([^/]*)',
'index.php?city_name=$matches[1]', 'top' );`